# Bootstrap, nifty modals and the shown.bs.modal event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am building a web application around a Bootstrap template that includes an add-on called "nifty modals". I need to be notified when the modal is shown to set the default focus. The template is bootstrap 1.3.1 based.

In my document.onReady I add a function to the event shown.bs.modal like this;

> $('#form-primary').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
>          console.log('shown'); })

But, I believe this event is not triggered by the nifty-modals, just the regular Bootstrap modal mechanisms. This might be, an probably are, by design.

Does anyone know If there is a way to get the nifty-modal code to trigge a similar event, or if it does?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see any way of doing this without modifying the nifty modal code.

In nifty modal's niftyEffects.js you could add this line:

```
el.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
    classie.add( modal, 'md-show' );
    overlay.removeEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );
    overlay.addEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );

    if( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ) {
        setTimeout( function() {
            classie.add( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
        }, 25 );
    }
    $(modal).trigger('shown.nifty.modal'); // <-- add this line
});
```

the event will fire as soon as the modal is shown (before the transition is complete).

http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/

Comment: Nice ! It would probably more appropriate to do something like  $(modal).trigger('shown.bs.nifty-modal') and add it to the main source of nifty modals.